# USB via Thunderbolt Bridge

Tags: usb, thunderbolt

I have a new MacBook Pro (Monterey) networked to a 2014 iMac (High Sierra) via Thunderbolt Bridge. Does anyone know how to access USB devices (e.g. memory stick, disc player) plugged into one computer from the other?

Answer (score 1):

I have a 2011 iMac with High Sierra and a 2013 iMac with Catalina connected using a Thunderbolt 1 bridge. I assume the same would be true when using a Thunderbolt 3 bridge even though the hardware is different.

The Network pane of System Preferences on the 2013 iMac shows the following IP address.

[image]

From Finder on the 2011 iMac, I can select "Connect to Server...". I then enter the following using the IP address from the previous image.

[image]

After connecting, a popup will appear where USB devices (as well as other shared drives and shared folders) on the 2013 iMac can be selected, as shown below. In this case, "Tuna" is an APFS volume on an USB Samsung T7 SSD where Catalina is installed.

[image]

Comment: David, many thanks for your reply, but in more modern OS's, Apple appears to have removed this capability. I can certainly replicate your instructions up to the final screenshot of selecting volumes to be mounted. However, simple USB devices such as a memory stick are simply not there! Interestingly, my back-up disc (also a USB device) IS accessible. I have no idea whether this behaviour is a feature or a bug, but it is certainly irritating! Thanks again. David Hoult.

Comment: Have you tried adding the missing USB devices to your list of Shared Folders on the Sharing pane of System Preferences?

Comment: Thanks. I had not tried that.  It certainly works for a SPECIFIC mounted USB device or disc, both of which are also remembered after dismounting, so it is 50% of the battle. 
I had hoped to mount and be able to see an arbitrary device (e.g. an old memory stick or disc) and then dismount or eject – 'plug and play' if you wish – as you would on the devices' attached computer. I guess it was too much to hope for.    
'FlexiHub' uses 'USB forwarding' that might do what I was looking for, but  its goal is to connect over long distances. 
Thanks again for your help.